# Confusion about Mitiq folding for zero noise extrapolation

Tags: qiskit, error-correction, error-mitigation

I'm reading the mitiq zero noise extrapolation documentation and I just can't make sense of how the scale_factor for folding work.

"The minimum scale factor is one (which corresponds to folding no gates). A scale factor of three corresponds to folding all gates locally. Scale factors beyond three begin to fold gates more than once."

Doc: https://mitiq.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/guide-zne.html

I made a quick qiskit example for convenience:

```
import qiskit as q
from mitiq.zne.scaling import fold_gates_from_left

n_qubits = 4
circ = QuantumCircuit(n_qubits)


circ.h(0)
for qubit in range(n_qubits - 1):
    circ.cx(qubit, qubit + 1)
circ.measure_all()
print(circ)
```

[image]

```
folded = fold_gates_from_left(circ, scale_factor=2.)
print("Folded circuit:", folded, sep="\n")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the input circuit has `d_in` gates, after applying unitary folding, one gets a circuit of `d_out >= d_in` gates.
The `scale_factor` (approximately) determines how much you want to scale `d_out` with respect to `d_in`. In other words, a subset of gates are folded such that `d_out` is approximately equal to `scale_factor * d_in`.

In your example:

```
d_in = 4
d_out = 8
scale_factor = 2.0
```

and indeed `d_out` is equal to `scale_factor * d_in`.